# jQuery live() not working with click, works with mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a problem of jQuery's `live()` function not working with `click, mousedown` but works with  'mouseover, mouseout`. For example the code below does not work:

**Not working:**

```
$("#info_rightclick_top").live('click', function() {
        marker_search_location.setPosition(rightclick_latlng);
});
```

**Working:**

```
$("#info_rightclick_top").live('mouseover', function() {
        $("#info_rightclick").css('background', 'url(' + base_url + '/images/template/icons/map_rightclick_top.png)');
});
```

I am using `live()` instead of `click()` because the `div` being selected does not exist when the document is loaded and is generated dynamically. I dont get it why using the `click` event on `live()` doesnt work? Any ideas?

### EDIT:

The above code that was not working previously now works when  I put it in a Google Maps Listener... **why is this so?**

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "rightclick", function(event) {
                $("#info_rightclick_top").click(function(e) {
                    alert("asd");
                });
            });
```

Comment: You have different code in the functions, so a likely problem is with the code inside your click handler. Try putting in an alert to see if the handler is being called.

Comment: user1222119: Added in `alert()` and its not being called... not sure what happened

Comment: Then the next likely problem is that your `div` is being covered by something else and not clickable. With your browser-specific tool (e.g. Firebug), use the select tool (magnifying class/mouse pointer) and hover over your new div to see if something is obstructing it. If this still doesn't solve the problem, you may have to post more code.

Comment: There doesnt seem to be anything obstructing it. Tried using Chrome's Inspector and Firefox's Firebug.

Comment: Edited original post with how I got it to work... but I dont understand why it works this way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's Event Bubbling. You should return false in your live function to prevent it.

[More details](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
$("#info_rightclick_top").live('click', function() {
        $("#info_rightclick").css('background', 'url(' + base_url + '/images/template/icons/map_rightclick_top.png)');
});
```

?

Comment: Yup, tried it and `click` doesnt work after replacing `mouseover` in the working code.